# C-wire on Weil-McLain CGA Series 2

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, boiler, wire

I have an old thermostat with only 2 wires connected to my Weil-McLain CGA Series 2 boiler.
I would like to replace it with a Nest thermostat.
I need to add a C-Wire in order for it to work. Luckily, the cable coming from my thermostat already has a 3rd wire that I can use. I just need to find where to connect the C wire on the boiler side.
In attached picture, blue pen drawing shows existing wirings.
The Low Water Cut Off has 4 wires, and one is already connected to the C Common terminal.
Can I just connect my thermostat’s C wire to the same terminal? (Green pen in drawing)
Thanks!

Aquastat is I believe Honeywell L4006E1067.
Low Water Cut Off is GuardDog LB-24E.
Orange and blue nuts connectors in picture connect all the above limits + thermostat in series to the thermostat connector on boiler.
All other limits and external devices are mounted per manual diagram.

[image: Thermostat wiring diagram]

[image: Boiler wiring from Manual]

[image: Boiler wiring picture]

[image: Zoom on upper wiring]

[image: Zoom on lower wiring]

[image: Additional Wiring picture]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any field-fitted limits wired in series with the spill switch and thermal fuse on your boiler?

Comment: In fact, can you post a photo of the wiring on your boiler?

Comment: Also, what model is your Aquastat?

Comment: Hi ThreePhaseEel, I added the missing info. Thanks a lot

Comment: Does the wire to the thermostat happen to have 4 wires?  If so you could use a separate transformer to power the Nest.  It looks like the way everything is wired now, even if you had a C-wire the nest could loose power if the aquastat or LWCO is tripped. (not an expert on your type of system tho)

Comment: Can you post closer-up shots of the wiring harnesses coming off the controller, and of where the black-and-yellow harness that extends off the top of your existing photo leads?

Comment: @JPhi1618
Unfortunately no 4th wire.
Could inverting thermostat and aquastat help the power losing problem you mentioned? Thermostat would receive continuous power by being connected to the Red and to the C, regardless of aquastat and lwco being on or off (both then connected in series to the white of tstat)

Comment: Can you provide some closeups of the wiring harness in front of and just below the control module?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel
I just posted more pictures. Awaiting pier review.
The black and yellow cable are connected in series to a sensor on damper/hood and another one located at bottom of boiler.